# how to check if the price exceeded 600

Tags: javascript

Class Tutorial – If Statements

A small bakery selling bread to local supermarkets and large convenience stores operates on the following basis:

- Orders for fewer than 50 loaves are priced at €1.10 per loaf
- Orders for between 50 and 90 loaves inclusive are priced at €0.95 per loaf
- Orders above 90 loaves are priced at €0.85 per loaf.

Prompt the user to enter the number of loaves they wish to buy.
Display the total price of the order in a text box

If the order total exceeds €60 then display a message in a text box telling the user they are allowed a 20% discount on any additional order of pancakes.

My question is 
is this the answer to this question as i am new to javascript?
if its not could someone provide me with a right answer?

I am struggling to display the answer in textbox and also i am struggling to display message saying you are allowed discount of 20% because i dont know how to check if the price exceeded 600 and one more thing 
can you just check the variables i have used if they are ok?

```
var n = prompt("Check your number", "How many items you want to buy?");

n = parseInt(n);

if (n  < 50)
   {
   alert("Total items you want to buy is  = " + n + "   The total price for these items is   =  " + n*1.10 + "  Euro");
   }
else if (n > 50 && n < 90)
   {
   alert("Total items you want to buy is  = " + n + "   The total price for these items is   =  " + n*0.95 + "  Euro");
   }

else if (n > 200)
   {
   alert("Total items you want to buy is  = " + n + "   The total price for these items is   =  " + n*0.85 + "  Euro");
   }
   else {
   alert("Please enter a valid number");
}
```

Comment: You know how to check if something is larger than `200` but not `600`? Also you will need to make a textbox so you can display something inside. So in your body add an `<input id="textbox" ... >`, and set the value using `document.getElementById("textbox").value = n`.

Comment: i got to the point where allow user to enter a qty, and if qty is less than 50 i  mulitplay it by the price 1.10 etc

Comment: check if its larger than 200 by saying

Comment: if ( n > 200) do something is that right

Comment: is my script correct or i am wrong, other than displaying the result in text box

Comment: It looks fine so far, just not complete.

Comment: so all i have to do is adding that line of code youve posted yeah?

Comment: That's what you would do for adding and setting the value of the textbox, but there is more to do than just that. SO isn't a coding service, see what you can do by yourself, and when there is a specific problem you are having you can ask it.

Comment: thanks Spencer, I know its not coding service but i just wanted to check if i am in the right track or not.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, your script is not correct.

Long answer:

You do not check if `n` is a positive integer. In case of an error `parseInt()` returns `NaN`, you can check for it with `isNaN()`. You may also strip leading zeros, some older engines (< ECMA-Script 5) might see these numbers as octal otherwise, no matter which base is given as the second argument to `parseInt()`.

```
n = parseInt(n);
if(isNaN(n) || n <= 0){
  alert("We, as the respectable bakery we are, "
         +"must insist on positive whole numbers. "
         +"Thank you for your patience");
}
else{
  // go on with the business
}
```

You do not offer to sell quantities of exactly 50 of bread and the price-range includes 90 loafs, too. Change the respective line to

```
if(n >=50 && n<= 90){
  // set proper price
}
```

The 20%-off is for pancakes, not bread, you need to hold the total sum in one variable, let's call it `totalSum` and at the end of all that mess check for it

```
if(totalSum >= 60){
  aler("You are entitled to a 20% discount for you next purchase of "
  +"pancakes! Buy some now, they are really yummy!");
}
```

Computers are also made to make repetitive tasks simpler. You have three times the same two sentences with the number of items and the sum the single differences. Just put them in variables.

```
var totalItemString = "Total items you want to buy is = ";
var totalSumString = " The total price for these items in Euro is = ";
```

NB: it is dangerous to compute in floats wrt. currency. In your case do everything in cents instead of Euros and do the division by 100 only for the print-out. You might use `toFixed()` for it.

But financial computing is complicated and is in parts even regulated by law (depending on the jurisdiction, of course). Shouldn't bother you at all as a beginner but if you like programming and want to go on with it: do not forget it.